# Spliting a dataframe into multiple 5-second dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a relatively big dataset that I want to split into multiple dataframes in **Python** based on a column containing a datetime object. The values in the column (that I want to split the dataframe by) are given in the following format:

1. `2015-11-01 00:00:05`

[You may assume the dataframe looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAMtd.png)

How can I **split the dataframe into 5-second intervals** in the following way:

1. 1st dataframe `2015-11-01 00:00:00 - 2015-11-01 00:00:05`,
2. 2nd dataframe `2015-11-01 00:00:05 - 2015-11-01 00:00:10`, and so on.

I also need to count the number of observations in each of resulting dataframes. In other, words, it would be nice if I could get another dataframe with 2 columns: 1st representing the splitted group (values of this column don't matter: they could be simply 1, 2, 3,.. indicating the order of the 5-second intervals ), 2nd column showing the number of observations belonging to the respective intervals

Comment: It isn't hard. What have you tried and where is your dataframe? We want to see data, not explanation.

Comment: The question has been edited. There is a hyperlink to the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best for store multiple `DataFrame`s is `dict`:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2015-11-01 00:00:00', periods=100, freq='S')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'a': range(100)})  
print (df.head(10))
                 Date  a
0 2015-11-01 00:00:00  0
1 2015-11-01 00:00:01  1
2 2015-11-01 00:00:02  2
3 2015-11-01 00:00:03  3
4 2015-11-01 00:00:04  4
5 2015-11-01 00:00:05  5
6 2015-11-01 00:00:06  6
7 2015-11-01 00:00:07  7
8 2015-11-01 00:00:08  8
9 2015-11-01 00:00:09  9

dfs={k.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'):v for k,v in 
                 df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='5S'))}

print (dfs['2015-11-01 00:00:00'])
                 Date  a
0 2015-11-01 00:00:00  0
1 2015-11-01 00:00:01  1
2 2015-11-01 00:00:02  2
3 2015-11-01 00:00:03  3
4 2015-11-01 00:00:04  4

print (dfs['2015-11-01 00:00:05'])
                 Date  a
5 2015-11-01 00:00:05  5
6 2015-11-01 00:00:06  6
7 2015-11-01 00:00:07  7
8 2015-11-01 00:00:08  8
9 2015-11-01 00:00:09  9
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response. I also need to count the number of observations in each of resulting dataframes.                                          
In other, words, it would be nice if I could get another dataframe with 2 columns: 1st representing the splitted group, 2nd column showing the number of observations belonging to the respective intervals.

Comment: So here will be all 5 values in my sample in new column?

Comment: Yes. But the original dataset that I am working on would have many more observations in each group. I need to get a new dataframe as a result in which the 1st column would indicate the splitted interval (values of this column don't matter: they could be simply 1, 2, 3,.. indicating the order of the 5-second intervals ) and the 2nd one containing the number of observations in each interval.

Comment: Then use `dfs={k.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'):v.assign(col=len(v.index)) for k,v in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='5S'))}`

Answer (score 1):

You can group by a floor of `Date` column by `5s`

```
f = '{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format

dfs = {f(k): g for k, g in df.groupby(df.Date.dt.floor('5s'))}
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response. I also need to count the number of observations in each of resulting dataframes. In other, words, it would be nice if I could get another dataframe with 2 columns: 1st representing the splitted group, 2nd column showing the number of observations belonging to the respective intervals.

Comment: @ArmanAsryan That was not part of your original question, so please don't ask it here. Open a new question for that.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ the main question has been edited. These two issues are closely linked to each other.

Comment: @ArmanAsryan the point is that it is disrespectful of the people whose time you’ve wasted asking one question and changing the question once they’ve answered.   It is best to treat the question you asked as one question. Mark the accepted answer, then ask a new question with the additional details

Comment: @piRSquared I did create a new, combined question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47133250/spliting-a-dataframe-into-multiple-5-second-dataframes-and-obtaining-count-in-py/47133267#47133267