# Spliting a dataframe into multiple 5-second dataframes and obtaining count in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, split, group-by

I have a relatively big dataset that I want to split into multiple dataframes in **Python** based on a column containing a datetime object. The values in the column (that I want to split the dataframe by) are given in the following format:

1. `2015-11-01 00:00:05`

[You may assume the dataframe looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAMtd.png)

How can I **split the dataframe into 5-second intervals** in the following way:

1. 1st dataframe `2015-11-01 00:00:00 - 2015-11-01 00:00:05`,
2. 2nd dataframe `2015-11-01 00:00:05 - 2015-11-01 00:00:10`, and so on.

I also need to count the number of observations in each of resulting dataframes. In other, words, it would be nice if I could get **another dataframe with 2 columns** (the desired output format can be found below):

[image]

- 1st column represents the splitted group (values of this column don't matter: they could be simply 1, 2, 3,.. indicating the order of the 5-second intervals, for example, 1 could refer to the period 2015-11-01 00:00:00 - 2015-11-01 00:00:05, 2 could refer to the period 2015-11-01 00:00:05 - 2015-11-01 00:00:10 
  and so on),
- 2nd column shows the number of observations falling in each respective interval.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spliting a dataframe into multiple 5-second dataframes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47131431/spliting-a-dataframe-into-multiple-5-second-dataframes-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `dictionary of DataFrame`s and add new column with [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
rng = pd.date_range('2015-11-01 00:00:00', periods=100, freq='S')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'a': range(100)})  
print (df.head(10))
                 Date  a
0 2015-11-01 00:00:00  0
1 2015-11-01 00:00:01  1
2 2015-11-01 00:00:02  2
3 2015-11-01 00:00:03  3
4 2015-11-01 00:00:04  4
5 2015-11-01 00:00:05  5
6 2015-11-01 00:00:06  6
7 2015-11-01 00:00:07  7
8 2015-11-01 00:00:08  8
9 2015-11-01 00:00:09  9

g = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='5S'))

dfs = {k.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'):v.assign(A=range(1,len(v)+1), B=len(v)) for k,v in g}

print (dfs['2015-11-01 00:00:05'])
                 Date  a  A  B
5 2015-11-01 00:00:05  5  1  5
6 2015-11-01 00:00:06  6  2  5
7 2015-11-01 00:00:07  7  3  5
8 2015-11-01 00:00:08  8  4  5
9 2015-11-01 00:00:09  9  5  5
```

If need count rows first aggreagte [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and for `Interval` is add 1 to index:

```
df1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='5S')).size().reset_index(name='Count')
df1['Interval'] = df1.index + 1
print (df1.head())
                 Date  Count  Interval
0 2015-11-01 00:00:00      5         1
1 2015-11-01 00:00:05      5         2
2 2015-11-01 00:00:10      5         3
3 2015-11-01 00:00:15      5         4
4 2015-11-01 00:00:20      5         5
```

Comment: I need a new resulting dataframe in which the1st column would show the interval (values could be 1, 2, 3,..., with 1 referring to the period 2015-11-01 00:00:00 - 2015-11-01 00:00:05, and so on), and 2nd column showing the number of observations falling in that interval.

Comment: OK, so what is desired ouptut for `rng = pd.date_range('2015-11-01 00:00:00', periods=100, freq='S')` `df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'a': range(100)})` ?

Comment: I just edited the question and showed the desired output format. For the generated dataset, all the values in the column 'Count' would simply be 5.

Comment: I need a new dataframe as a result, so that I can later check if the count of observations follows a Poisson distribution.

Comment: Thank You. I think this is result I wanted.